# reads a string and then prints it surrounded by a frame

Tags: java

I need write a code which reads a string and then prints it surrounded by a frame
consisting of asterisks and with width which matches the length of the string.
For example, if the string is `Shakespeare`, then the program should print following:-

```
*****************
*               *
*  Shakespeare  *
*               *
*****************
```

Note: if `str` is the reference to a string, then `str.length()` is its length.

I`m totally lost! i start study for my self and i need some help! Someone can give a cod for this situation or send me a link for any video to learn this?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Hello new user, Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. Please kindly add your code you have been working with so far and we might help.

Comment: Or just think for a bit and try something :) then ask for help. Asking for someone else to do it for you is a bad manner. We actually do code for money you know. I would be glad to help  someone but at least try yourself first

Comment: i`m asking for a way to learn this! if you have some material to help me how learn this i`ll be glad! tnks for your attention

Answer (score 0):

I will cut the problem into smaller pieces, try to figure out the exact code yourself.

You need to print the following lines (let `l` be the string's length):

- A line full of (l + 6) asterisks.
- A line with one asterisk, followed by (l + 4) spaces and another asterisk at the end
- A line with one asterisk, 2 spaces, the string, another 2 spaces, and another asterisk at the end
- A line with one asterisk, followed by (l + 4) spaces and another asterisk at the end
- A line full of (l + 6) asterisks.

Note that we print (l + 6) asterisks and (l + 4) spaces is to account for the padding in the sample output.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code if you really need it.

```
public static void main(String[] args){


    String str = "Shakespeare";

    printWithBorder(str);
}

public static void printWithBorder(String str) {
    int len = str.length();

    //1st line.
    for (int i = 0; i < len + 4; i++) {
        System.out.print("*");
    }
    System.out.println("");

    //second line.
    System.out.print("*");
    for (int i = 0; i < len + 2; i++) {
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
    System.out.println("*");
    //third line
    System.out.println("* " + str + " *");

    //print forth line as the second line.
    System.out.print("*");
    for (int i = 0; i < len + 2; i++) {
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
    System.out.println("*");
    //print fifth line as 1st line.
    for (int i = 0; i < len + 4; i++) {
        System.out.print("*");
    }
    System.out.println("");
}
```